# ReactJS - Gallery App - Previous Picture is shown until next picture is fully loaded

Tags: reactjs

When the user click the next button, the next picture in the gallery will be loaded with some title and description.

The first picture is loaded with title and description.
When i click next, the description and title changes instantly. But i can see the first picture only. It takes few seconds to show the second picture. So it will confuse the users.

```
removeFirstPicture(id) { //onclick next
        let pictures = this.state.pictures;        
        return pictures.filter(p => p.picture_id !== id);
    }

render() {
   let p = [...this.state.pictures].slice(0, 1);
}
```

The return function has a component which will receive title,picture and description as props.

I tried to set the picture to null

```
let pic = null
        setTimeout(() => {
            pic = <p><CardImg top src={this.props.picture} alt={this.props.title} /></p>;
        }, 300);
```

So i thought, i would load null for every next button click and after 300ms it will try to load original picture. But it is not working. The picture is always empty

please give me some solutions. 
After clicking the next button, the first image should not be displayed for those few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how do you get *next* image but should do it with Promises. Once promises is resolved you are good to change your state, like i do in this example:

```
class Picture extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLoaded: false,
      next: 'white'
    }

    this.fetchNextPicture = this.fetchNextPicture.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchNextPicture()
  }

  fetchNextPicture(){
    this.setState({ isLoaded: true });
    // here i just simulate async call, so you can change it to fetch or something else
    return new Promise(
      (resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve({ next: "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16) }), 2000),
      (reject) => reject('Something went wrong')
      ).then(
        // Promise is resolved & we good to change our state to new
        data => this.setState({ next: data.next, text: data.next, isLoaded: false}),
        error => console.log(error)
    )
  }

  render() {
    const style = {
      width: '300px',
      height: '300px',
      backgroundColor: this.state.next,
      color: 'tomato',
      lineHeight: '300px',
      textAlign: 'center',
      fontSize: '20px'
    }

    return (
        <div>
          {this.state.isLoaded 
            ? <div> loading </div>
            : <div style={style}>
                {this.state.text}
              </div>}
        <button onClick={this.fetchNextPicture}>
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[`Worked example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/98034/)

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps() {

        if(!this.state.lazyLoading) {
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                lazyLoading: true
            });
        }
    }`  and onImageLoad funtion i did `onImageLoaded() {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            lazyLoading: false
        });
    }`

Comment: @Mahesh how do you pass `props` to this component with `componentWillReceiveProps`?

Answer (score -1):

One approach is to give the `CardImg` a `loading` state, give it a default value of `true`. You should show a placeholder image whenever `loading` is `true`. Then, you could use `image.onload` to set `loading` to `false` when the image finished loading.

[image.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/image.onload)

[Example of image.onload usage in React](https://www.andrewhfarmer.com/detect-image-load/)

Comment: I can successfully do it for componentDidMount. But for the next image onwards, it should be written in componentWillUpdate, which i am not able to figure out how to do it. It goes with infinite loop. I need to write some condition to break it. But it goes either in the infinite loop or not updating the dom :(

Comment: Update the state in the event handler.